# Unable to bind jibx idea tool

Tags: xml, jibx

> Error:Jibx Compiler: Error running binding compiler
>   org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Binding .DS_Store is unusable because of validation errors
>       at org.jibx.binding.Utility.loadBinding(Utility.java:358)
>       at org.jibx.binding.Utility.loadFileBinding(Utility.java:420)
>       at org.jibx.binding.Compile.compile(Compile.java:217)
>       at com.adamweigold.jibx.compiler.JibxBuilder.build(JibxBuilder.java:72)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1230)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:904)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:976)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:870)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:695)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:386)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:193)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:294)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Apple OS X operating system, .DS_Store is a file that stores custom attributes of its containing folder, such as the position of icons or the choice of a background image. It does not any role in building of any project or code. hence it is also usually git-ignored. Since it only stores metaData, hence this problem was solved by deleting all the .DS_Store folder in directory.

.DS_Store files impose additional burden on revision control process: They are frequently changed and therefore appear in commits, unless specifically excluded

.DS_Store files have been known to adversely affect copy operations.

These reasons also may add to execution of XML script